# How to add a background colour to unselected label for a tabbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to design a tabbar with this pattern of design

But so I'm not able to make the unselected tab have a background just like this

[image]

When I try I end with something like this

Is it posible to use the Defaulttabbarcontroller to make this design or there is a way to design my own custom tab bar

[image]

Comment: Can you include your current code-snippet

Comment: could you please add what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

This widget will provide you idea, I am using `color.withOpacity`, you may use colorFilter or others widget,

[image]

```dart
class TabBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabBarDemo> createState() => _TabBarDemoState();
}

class _TabBarDemoState extends State<TabBarDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this)
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.shade900);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                ActionChip(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.animateTo(0);
                  },
                  label: Text(
                    "All",
                    style: controller.index == 0
                        ? textStyle
                        : textStyle.copyWith(
                            color: textStyle.color!.withOpacity(.3),
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                ActionChip(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.animateTo(1);
                  },
                  label: Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.ac_unit,
                          size: 12,
                          color: controller.index == 1
                              ? Colors.red
                              : Colors.red.withOpacity(.4),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Income",
                        style: controller.index == 1
                            ? textStyle
                            : textStyle.copyWith(
                                color: textStyle.color!.withOpacity(.3),
                              ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                ActionChip(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.animateTo(2);
                    },
                    label: Text(
                      "Expenses",
                      style: controller.index == 2
                          ? textStyle
                          : textStyle.copyWith(
                              color: textStyle.color!.withOpacity(.3),
                            ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: controller,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Make sure to initialize the variable as I did on top, I am using `final textStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.shade900);`

Comment: Yh, I’ve sorted it, thanks

Comment: Also you can use the same logic for `ActionChip` 's   `backgroundColor`

Comment: yh, I already did that. Thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 0):

Based on your case and design, I go with Chips and [Wrap](https://youtu.be/z5iw2SeFx2M) widgets if I want to build your design. Then I have a Container below them that acts as TabBarView. So, you need to change the child of the Container when the user taps on the Chip.

However, if you want to stick with TabBar then you need to set a theme when you launch the app. This is how I assign my themes, usually.

[image]